Spring Boot: URL to file in src/main/resources not found in Docker container
I have a Spring Boot backend application which has following part in the application.properties:
token.json_file_url=${TOKEN_JSON_FILE_URL:file:src/main/resources/localdev/user-claims.json}

${TOKEN_JSON_FILE_URL} env variable is not set, so the default file:src/main/... is in effect.
In a bundled library it's used like this when a REST call is made:
@Value("${token.json_file_url}")
private String userClaimsTokenJsonFileUrl;
...
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(); //Jackson
Map<String, Object> map =
objectMapper.readValue(new URL(this.userClaimsTokenJsonFileUrl), new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});

Now executing the fat-jar generated by spring-boot-maven plugin runs perfectly fine in console via java -jar the-app.jar.
But copying the same jar into a docker container and firing a REST call against that yields a
java.io.FileNotFoundException: src/main/resources/localdev/user-claims.json.
How can that be?
To be complete, here's the Dockerfile:
FROM amazoncorretto:17-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app/the-app.jar
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-jar", "the-app.jar"]

I also extracted the jar inside the container and the structure is:
BOOT-INF/classes/localdev/user-claims.json
It's there. It just can't be found running in a Docker container as opposed to running my jar locally.
Any ideas?

Project Tree
demo-springboot-json-app
├── Dockerfile
├── my-docker-data
│   └── token-003.json
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   └── main
│       ├── java
│       │   └── com
│       │       └── example
│       │           └── demo
│       │               ├── DemoApplication.java
│       │               └── HelloController.java
│       └── resources
│           ├── application.properties
│           ├── logback.xml
│           └── token-001.json
└── token-002.json


Test JSON
token-001.json
{
    "token": "AAAA",
    "expiresIn": 1100
}

token-002.json
{
    "token": "BBBB",
    "expiresIn": 2200
}

token-003.json
{
    "token": "CCCC",
    "expiresIn": 3300
}

pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.8</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-springboot-json-app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo-springboot-json-app</name>
    <description>demo-springboot-json-app project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

application.properties
spring.application.name=demo

token.json_file_url=${TOKEN_JSON_FILE_URL:token-001.json}

logback.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="Console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d [%thread] %-5level %-50logger{40} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
     
    <appender name="RollingFile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>app.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d [%thread] %-5level %-50logger{40} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
         
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>1MB</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>10MB</totalSizeCap>
            <cleanHistoryOnStart>true</cleanHistoryOnStart>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>
     
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    </root>
</configuration>

DemoApplication.java
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}

HelloController.java
package com.example.demo;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Map;
import java.net.URL;

@RestController
public class HelloController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloController.class);

    @Value("${token.json_file_url}")
    private String userClaimsTokenJsonFileUrl;


    @GetMapping("/hello2/{name}")
    public String sayHello2(
            @PathVariable String name,
            @RequestParam(value = "greeting", defaultValue = "Hello") String greeting
    ) {

        logger.info(">>>> Token JSON File: {}", userClaimsTokenJsonFileUrl);

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, Object> map = null;
                
        File file = new File(userClaimsTokenJsonFileUrl);
        if (file.exists()) {
            try {
                map = objectMapper.readValue(file, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
                });
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        } else {
            ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource(userClaimsTokenJsonFileUrl);
            try ( InputStream inputStream = resource.getInputStream()) {
                {
                    if (inputStream == null) {
                        String errMsg = "File not found in classpath or file system: " + userClaimsTokenJsonFileUrl;
                        logger.error("{}", errMsg);
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException(errMsg);
                    }
                    map = objectMapper.readValue(inputStream, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
                    });
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                logger.error("{}", ex);
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        }

        if (map != null) {
            String token = (String) map.get("token");
            String expiresIn = String.valueOf(map.get("expiresIn"));
            logger.info(">>>> Token: " + token);
            logger.info(">>>> Expires In: " + expiresIn);
        } else {
            logger.error("CAN NOT READ MAP");
        }


        String msg = String.format("%s, %s!", greeting, name);
        logger.info(">>>> {} ", msg);
        return msg;
    }
    
}

Dockerfile
# Build
FROM maven:3.9.5-eclipse-temurin-17-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /BUILDTMP
COPY pom.xml .
COPY src ./src
RUN mvn clean package -DskipTests

# Runtime
FROM amazoncorretto:17-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=my-app.jar

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /BUILDTMP/target/${JAR_FILE} ./app.jar

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-jar", "app.jar"]

Build and Run
Build
mvn clean package

Run
Terminal-1
java -jar target/demo-springboot-json-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Test-1
Terminal-2
curl http://localhost:8080/hello2/ABCD12345678

check Terminal-1 console output
>>>> Token JSON File: token-001.json
>>>> Token: AAAA
>>>> Expires In: 1100

App read jar file's token-001.json success.(Read file from classpath resource)
In Terminal-1 , Ctrl + C , Stop App.
Test-2 Set Environment
Terminal-1
export TOKEN_JSON_FILE_URL=token-002.json

java -jar target/demo-springboot-json-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Terminal-2
curl http://localhost:8080/hello2/ABCD12345678

check Terminal-1 console output
>>>> Token JSON File: token-002.json
>>>> Token: BBBB
>>>> Expires In: 2200

App read token-002.json success.(Read file from Environment Config)
In Terminal-1 , Ctrl + C , Stop App.
Build Docker Container
docker build \
  --build-arg JAR_FILE=demo-springboot-json-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar \
  -t my-app-image .

Docker Test-1
Terminal-1
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 my-app-image

Terminal-2
curl http://localhost:8080/hello2/ABCD12345678

check Terminal-1 console output
>>>> Token JSON File: token-001.json
>>>> Token: AAAA
>>>> Expires In: 1100

App read jar file's token-001.json success.(Read file from classpath resource)
In Terminal-1 , Ctrl + C , Stop App.
Docker Test-2 Set Environment
Terminal-1
docker run -it \
  -p 8080:8080 \
  -v `pwd`/my-docker-data:/conf \
  -e TOKEN_JSON_FILE_URL=/conf/token-003.json \
  my-app-image

Terminal-2
curl http://localhost:8080/hello2/ABCD12345678

check Terminal-1 console output
>>>> Token JSON File: /conf/token-003.json
>>>> Token: CCCC
>>>> Expires In: 3300

App read token-003.json success.(Read file from Environment Config)
In Terminal-1 , Ctrl + C , Stop App.
Another Solution About Read File
I did not use the following writing method. The following writing method may be what you want:
    public InputStream loadFile(String path) throws Exception {
        URL url;
        
        //Read From Internet
        if (path.startsWith("http://") || path.startsWith("https://")) {
            url = new URL(path);
        } 

        //Read From Local File
        else if (path.startsWith("file:/")) {
            url = new URL(path);
        } 

        else {
        
        //Read From Classpath
        
            ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
            url = classLoader.getResource(path);
            if (url == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("File not found in classpath: " + path);
            }
        }
        
        return url.openStream();
    }

application.properties
# Read From Classpath File
token.json_file_url=${TOKEN_JSON_FILE_URL:token-001.json}

# Read From Local File
token.json_file_url=${TOKEN_JSON_FILE_URL:file:///path/to/your/token-002.json}

# Read From Internet File
token.json_file_url=${TOKEN_JSON_FILE_URL:http://hello.world.com/token-003.json}


Thanks for your effort! I actually realised why it wasn't working in Docker but from JAR in the IDE. It's stupid, will add it to the answer

OK so actually the problem was much more stupid than I realised...
I was executing the JAR from my root project directory.
Like java -jar target/the-app.jar.
What I didn't realize was that the path root/src/main/resources/localdev/... was available to the code running in the jar... It was not using the packed resources INSIDE the jar, but the external files...
That's why the
new URL(file:src/main/resources/...) 

worked for the jar, while of course in the Docker container, this path wasn't there.
Again, my mistake was that I thought the JAR used the resources packed inside the JAR, which it did not!
Fixed it by copying the files also into the Docker container.
